# Swift CGPoint unusual behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, cgpoint

I have a ViewController and the following code.

```
var point: CGPoint?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Initial tile coords
    point = CGPointMake(0, 0)

    // Update UI
    updateUI()
}

func updateUI() {
    println("Update UI")

}
```

Where I initialise the tile coords, I can see that the x and y values of my CGPoint are correctly set to 0.0. But when I jump into the updateUI() method, the x and y values of my CGPoint have changed! They change to something different each time.

Does anyone know what may be causing this behaviour? Or do you think I should raise a bug report with Apple?

Regards
Stephen

Comment: When you say that they have changed, is it just the debugger that is showing them differently? Have you tried logging the values of x and y?

Comment: No I haven't but the values are then used to get a value from an array and it doesn't fund a value which is definitely there. Will print the values to see what happens

Comment: What else is in your controller?

Comment: Just FYI, you can use `CGPoint(x:,y:)` to initialise instead of `CGPointMake`. I'm guessing either the importer is smart enough to omit the `Make` which doesn't read good or the initialiser was explicitly added...

Comment: Bill there are some other initializations, but nothing which references or changes the CGPoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having some other issues...But this particular issues appears to be related to the debugger, rather than the actual values. I have filed a bug report with Apple :)

I appreciate all the responses guys